# How can I clone all field values when creating a node translation (entity_translation) programmatically?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I use `entity_translation` and have an `en` node currently without translations. Assume it has fields `field_foo` and `field_bar` so currently they are:

```
$node->field_foo['en'][0]['value'] = 'foo';
$node->field_bar['en'][0]['value'] = 'bar';
```

I want to programmatically add an`fr` translation but only translate `field_foo` so I do:

```
$node->field_foo['fr'][0]['value'] = 'foo FR';

entity_translation_get_handler('node', $node)->setTranslation(array(
  'translate' => 0,
  'language' => 'fr',
  'source' => 'en'
), $node);
field_attach_update('node', $node);
```

This works but now if I edit (or devel) the `fr` node, `field_bar` is empty. On the frontend it does show "bar" which is the `en` value, but I've noticed that if I create the translation via the Drupal UI then the `field_bar` is not empty and contains a copy of the `en` value.

So, does anyone know of a way that the API will copy all values upon translation creation? Or should I be doing that myself manually via the code?

Comment: Hi, did you manage with issue?

Comment: @makbuk I used custom code. I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing it manually via code:

```
function _populate_translation_values($node, $targetLanguage) {
  $fields = field_info_instances('node', $node->type);
  foreach($fields as $fieldName=>$fieldInstance) {
    $fieldInfo = field_info_field($fieldName);

    // only process translatable fields
    if (!$fieldInfo['translatable']) continue;

    // ignore fields which are complicated to copy - could be fixed in the future
    if (in_array($fieldInfo['type'], array('field_collection'))) continue;

    // skip fields which already have a value in the target language
    if (isset($node->{$fieldName}[$targetLanguage])) continue;

    // skip fields which don't have a value in the source language
    if (!isset($node->{$fieldName}[$node->language])) continue;

    // copy value
    $node->{$fieldName}[$targetLanguage] = $node->{$fieldName}[$node->language];
  }
}
```